# gradle dependency property with module exclude

Tags: android, gradle

i try to write **central dependency file** for my multi-module project.

```
ext {
    supportVersion = '25.4.0'
    junitVersion = '4.12'

    supportDependencies = [
        design:            "com.android.support:design:${supportVersion}",
        fragment:          "com.android.support:support-fragment:${supportVersion}",
        recyclerView:      "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportVersion}"
    ]
    ...
}
```

to use them in modules

```
compile supportDependencies.design
compile supportDependencies.fragment
compile supportDependencies.recyclerView
```

but some dependencies have `exclude` to be compiled

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
```

when i try to write property how

```
testingDependencies = [
        espresso:          ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
]
```

i receive compile time syntaxis errors

Is it possible to create library-property with exclude in extensions to be compiled in module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have solved my problem by adding in **central dependency file**

```
ext {   
   espressoVersion = '3.0.1'

   testingDependencies = [
        espresso: "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:${espressoVersion}"
   ]
}
```

and in module

```
androidTestCompile(testingDependencies.espresso, {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
```

so i have still one file with used dependency versions and can simple update versions in all modules

Answer (score 0):

Of course you get a syntax error. It is Groovy syntax you have to use. In your first example you simple define a `Map` `String` key to `String` value and then use those strings.

You could e. g. instead of a `Map<String, String>` define a `Map<String, List>` and in the list put in first place the dependency and in the second place the excludes as `List<Map>` and then iterate over that list, adding the excludes. (`group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'` is just syntactic sugar for a map, essentially you call a method `exclude` with a `Map` as argument)

Or you could change completely to making your central definitions closures that you use to apply the respective dependencies, something like

```
testingDependencies = [
    espresso: {
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2') {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        }
    }
]

configure dependencies, testingDependencies.espresso
```

or something like that.

Comment: where should i use `configure` ? I receive `Error:Could not find method configure() for arguments...` by sync. Could you please more explane, how i can iterate over list and add the excludes?